# Does apt mount /boot on kernel updates?

Tags: boot, apt, kernel, mount

I'm a Gentoo user. On my setups, I usually set the `noauto` flag for the `/boot` partition. Maybe its just some good  'ol fashion paranoia, but I like not to mount `/boot` unless really needed. Because I need to compile my own kernel, I have a kernel update script that mounts `/boot` for me.

I've just installed a Ubuntu server for a client, and want to set `noauto` for `/boot`. Can `apt` take care of `/boot` mounting when its updating the kernel, initramfs and/or grub?

Comment: You don't mention any disadvantage of having /boot mounted in the first place? Plus for most users it is mounted with / which is always mounted anyway.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: Ubuntu default is included in /, yes. But the "old school" way is to keep it on a separate partition. So that if / encounters corruption, you can still launch the kernel, initramfs and fsck. This separation is the default for many distros. On top, something that's not mounted cannot corrupt during a power loss.

Comment: If you have a power loss without UPS then 99.99% of the time read only /boot would be the least of your concerns. As far as "old school" I can appreciate that. We all have different comfort zones.